# Auto Specify Row heights

Tags: css

I've created this CSS code to give me 3 responsive columns, but.. in mobile are sick and Ipad too.
Anyway, my real question is:

1 How to put the 3 rows with auto fit. Because they are all with the same AUTO SIZE.
When none of the boxes contain any content I would like the grid to look small and not BIG.

```
.pagewrap {
 *background: #6B949F;
 display: grid;
 grid-template-columns:210px 850px 210px;
 grid-template-rows: auto auto auto;
 grid-gap: 10px;
 justify-content: center;

}

.content {
 text-align: left;
 background: #1C1C1C;
 box-shadow:0 6px 6px -6px #000;
 border-radius: 3px;
}
  .content ul li {
    width: 190px;
    padding:5px 10px;
    background:none;
    text-transform: none;
}
  .content ul li a {
    display: block;
    padding:0 15px 0;
    color:#BDBDBD;
    background:transparent;
    font-size: 15px;
    transition: all 0.35s ease; 
}
  .content ul li a:hover {
    background:#424242;
    border-radius: 1px;
    color:#fff;
}     
 
.middle {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 8px;
 text-align: center;
 background: #E6E6E6;
 box-shadow:0 6px 6px -6px #000;
 border-radius: 3px;
} 
 
.sidebar {

 padding: 8px;
 text-align: center;
 background: #1C1C1C;
 box-shadow:0 6px 6px -6px #000;
 border-radius: 3px;
 color:#BDBDBD;
}
```

I want boxes like this.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLhJE.png

Comment: ***"...in mobile are sick"***? what does that mean?

Comment: I have to configure the "width" but thats not what i want right now. Can you help me with the ROW SIZE?

Comment: in HTML, just do `<div class="row" style="width: XXXpx">`

Answer (score 0):

try `d-flex` and `justify-content-between`.

`d-flex` will align them into one row and `justify-content-between` will align them like this: |right center left|

Comment: Nop does not work. justify-content: center; already give me the CENTER POSITION.. that's ok for me.. but now i want BOX -SIZE to be NOT equal.